# Java SWT CheckedListBox

Tags: java, checkbox, swt, checkboxlist, checkedlistbox

I could not find CheckedListBox in Java SWT. Please, point me to a way of extending `List` to support checkboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try to use table instead of list. Look at this [snippet](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/TableWithCheckBoxCell.htm)

Answer (score 6):

Just add SWT.CHECK to your TableViewer:

```
new TableViewer(container, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.SINGLE);
```

[image: Creates a table that looks like this]

Answer (score 1):

Use JFace CheckboxTableViewer:

```
CheckboxTableViewer viewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(
        parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

i've added a button selectAll on the above snippet and added the following event

```
Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    Button selectAll= new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    selectAll.setFont(FontUtils.getMsSansSerifFont());
    selectAll.setLayoutData(gridData);
    selectAll.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            table.selectAll();
        }
    });
```

But the checkboxes are not selected?

Comment: This is not your question!

To "select" checkboxes you need to `check` them.